# Influx - string compression

Tags: compression, influxdb

Does influx have dictionary style compression for strings that repeat frequently. I found a mention here: https://www.influxdata.com/blog/new-storage-engine-time-structured-merge-tree/ but unable to find out if the feature is already implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was added to the design docs here, but it appears to be more of a proposal:

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/commit/06016882abc6f1a9d992fa0b153b7bbc50bfb500

I only see snappy string compression referenced in the source (although it could be somewhere else):

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/tsdb/tsm1/string.go